# Microphone is not being detected in Safari on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, ios-simulator

What I am trying to do is very simple.

Environment description:

macOS Catalina version 10.15.7
iOS Simulator version 12.3
Target device iPhone 11 (iOS 13.2.2)

Open Safari > go to website > https://mictests.com

Result: "Could not find any media devices. It is very likely that your browser does not allow access to these devices."

The Simulator does have access to the microphone. I can use Siri just fine. Only Safari cannot access the mic. I'm really stuck here, any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Hi Ali,
I am just curios, when you click on test, was there an alert for Microphone permission appears ?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the Xcode iOS Simulator has a mock audio inputs listed as `Mock audio device 1` and `Mock audio device 2`. Safari appears to be unable to use the "actual" microphone. Siri, system features such as dictation, and apps developed and run on the similar are able to access the microphone of the host device.